# How to reduce the number of same edge label between two Vertex in Titan

Tags: graph, titan, gremlin

Let's say we have two type of Vertex: LOGIN_USER(property:user_id) and IP(property:ip), EDGE between them is : LOGIN(property:session_id, login_time).

This model's problem is that two many edges between one USER and IP(Can be thousands).
Is there anyway to reduce the edge number of the two vertexes and at the same time can keep property: sessionId and login_time?  We want to filter these two properties for some query.
Edge property doesn't support cardinality:list which vertex property support.

If put all edge property into Vertex, does it impact performance to fetch the Vertex?
When titan load property for a Vertex?? When traversal to a Vertex, let's g.V(1).next(), does Titan load all Property for the Vertex?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "thousands" of edges between USER and IP, do you think it could actually be "millions" or "tens of millions" or more? If not, then "thousands" should not be a problem for Titan with [vertex centric indices](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html#vertex-indexes). Index your edge properties and you should have fast ordering and traversals.

When you start to get deep into "millions", you might start to experience some problems - for me that has always been with processing global queries with titan-hadoop as the Vertex and its edges must be held in memory. That can make for some trouble spots when you're doing global analytics. From an operational perspective, Titan was always happy to keep writing edges into the millions on a vertex, but I'd tend to avoid it. Of course, much of my experience with this came before [vertex cutting](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/graph-partitioning.html#_vertex_cut) in Titan 1.0:

> Cutting a vertex means storing a subset of that vertex’s adjacency
>   list on each partition in the graph. In other words, the vertex and
>   its adjacency list is partitioned thereby effectively distributing the
>   load on that single vertex across all of the instances in the cluster
>   and removing the hot spot.

which you might experiment with as you start to grow supernodes into the millions.

I suppose the other option for supernodes in the millions of edges would be to model around it. Perhaps you introduce some structure between USER and IP. Convert that single LOGIN edge to some vertices/edges that might introduce a time concept between them like:

USER -> LOGIN_YEAR -> LOGIN_MONTH -> IP

So now, instead of creating just one edge between USER and IP you create a LOGIN_YEAR vertex and a LOGIN_MONTH vertex.

Comment: Thanks. We are testing DynamoDB now. Which Storage are you using now?? Currently we found with too many edges between two vertexes, it's  slow.  Also, when we run g.V('userId').out('LOGIN').in().values(), will see lots of duplicated vertexes,  Titan return all edge's inVertex, although most of the edge are routed to the same Vertex.

Comment: my experience is with cassandra. i think your vertex duplication is expected for that traversal. You traversed `out` from the USER but then traversed back `in` and the original vertex you traversed away from is in that path. You have to filter out those paths that lead back to the start vertex. I suspect that you also want to remove duplicates. So your traversal would look like: `g.V('userId').as('x').out('LOGIN').in().where(neq('x')).dedup().values()`

Comment: What's the data volume your experience? Billion level? How about query latency for  `g.V('userId').as('x').out('LOGIN').in().where(neq('x')).dedu‌​p().values()` ?

Comment: yes - billions of edges total in the graph, but never went beyond low millions on a single vertex. i don't know that you will see that much difference in speed between my traversal and yours - i just wanted to filter out some of your duplicates. if you want to speed up your traversal when it hits a vertex with lots of edges, you will need to filter the edges better by creating some vertex centric indices and using them in your traversals. In that way, Titan should push down the filter to the database and return less data.

Comment: Thanks your advice stephen. I am using Cassandra now.  I set Vertex Partition and Vertex-Centrics index for the edge.  But my query is pretty slow, I am not sure if it's common.  g.V('userId').as('x').out('LOGIN').in().where(neq('x')).dedu‌​p().values()  will cost hundreds seconds. Does Titan can parallel query for it? I also test limit() to try to limit result, but it's still slow. Does Titan get result first, then do 'limit' ?  How to know Titan's execute plan?

Comment: That query isn't using a vertex centric index. There is no edge filtering. You're getting a list of every single user who logged into all the same IPs as the starting vertex. If that's the query result you need, it will probably always be "slow" i you have tens/hundreds/more of thousands of edges to IP. I assume you created an vertex centric index on the `login_time` - if you included some limit based on that field, it would probably help depending on the size of the slice. You might also denormalize the user_id to the edge and index/filter on that when going back from IP to LOGIN_USER.